# Image Processing - Implementing Sobel Filter

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

I've got a task to implement Sobel filter which is, as you know, an image processing filter for edge detection.
But unfortunately, I've got no experience in image processing field, to the extent that I don't even know how images are represented in computer. Totally no knowledge in this field.

I've read some papers and PDFs but they focus on many topics which I feel that I may not need them for my task.

I'd be happy to know your suggestions or if there is any particular paper, PDF, tutorial or quick guide for this purpose.

Thank you

EDIT:

Thank you all :)
The result of our work can be downloaded from [here](http://www.4shared.com/office/HiM0drucce/SobelFilter_Siavashi_Kianineja.html).

Comment: Voting to close as resource rec.

Answer (score 30):

It's pretty easy, you just need to convolve your image with a Sobel filter. A Sobel filter has two kernels, x-direction kernel and y-direction kernel. The x-direction kernel detects horizontal edges, and y-direction kernels detects vertical edges.

x-direction kernel (the size is 3x3)

```
float kernelx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, 
                       {-2, 0, 2}, 
                       {-1, 0, 1}};
```

y-direction kernel

```
float kernely[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, 
                        {0,  0,  0}, 
                        {1,  2,  1}};
```

To calculate the convolution at pixel (x,y), define a window of size equal to the kernel size (source code to calculate magnitude in x and magnitude in y are identical):

```
double magX = 0.0; // this is your magnitude

for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
{
    for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
    {            
        int xn = x + a - 1;
        int yn = y + b - 1;

        int index = xn + yn * width;
        magX += image[index] * kernelx[a][b];
    }
 }
```

Note that the input is a grayscale image and it can be represented as 1D array of double (This is just a trick, since a pixel value in coordinate (x,y) can be accessed with index = [x + y * width] )

To calculate magnitude in pixel (x,y) given magX and magY :

**mag = sqrt( magX^2 + magY^2 )**

Comment: would it make any sense to combine the horizontal and vertical kernels by making one the real part and one the imaginary part, and then you can find the magnitude by getting the abs(the result)?

Comment: @azer89 I doubt whether simple multiplication of `image` and `kernelx` will work, since we require convolution, right?

Comment: Look at this blog: [2d convolution](http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution2d_example.html)

Answer (score 22):

The most simple explanation of the **Sobel operator** I've seen to this date is from [**Saush's blog**](http://blog.saush.com/2011/04/20/edge-detection-with-the-sobel-operator-in-ruby/), a tech enthusiast who once met Sobel himself:

[image]

[The post](http://blog.saush.com/2011/04/20/edge-detection-with-the-sobel-operator-in-ruby/) describes in (not too many) details how to implement the filter, and shares Ruby source-code for demonstration purposes:

```
require 'chunky_png'

class ChunkyPNG::Image
  def at(x,y)
    ChunkyPNG::Color.to_grayscale_bytes(self[x,y]).first
  end
end

img = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file('engine.png')

sobel_x = [[-1,0,1],
           [-2,0,2],
           [-1,0,1]]

sobel_y = [[-1,-2,-1],
           [0,0,0],
           [1,2,1]]

edge = ChunkyPNG::Image.new(img.width, img.height, ChunkyPNG::Color::TRANSPARENT)

for x in 1..img.width-2
  for y in 1..img.height-2
    pixel_x = (sobel_x[0][0] * img.at(x-1,y-1)) + (sobel_x[0][1] * img.at(x,y-1)) + (sobel_x[0][2] * img.at(x+1,y-1)) +
              (sobel_x[1][0] * img.at(x-1,y))   + (sobel_x[1][1] * img.at(x,y))   + (sobel_x[1][2] * img.at(x+1,y)) +
              (sobel_x[2][0] * img.at(x-1,y+1)) + (sobel_x[2][1] * img.at(x,y+1)) + (sobel_x[2][2] * img.at(x+1,y+1))

    pixel_y = (sobel_y[0][0] * img.at(x-1,y-1)) + (sobel_y[0][1] * img.at(x,y-1)) + (sobel_y[0][2] * img.at(x+1,y-1)) +
              (sobel_y[1][0] * img.at(x-1,y))   + (sobel_y[1][1] * img.at(x,y))   + (sobel_y[1][2] * img.at(x+1,y)) +
              (sobel_y[2][0] * img.at(x-1,y+1)) + (sobel_y[2][1] * img.at(x,y+1)) + (sobel_y[2][2] * img.at(x+1,y+1))

    val = Math.sqrt((pixel_x * pixel_x) + (pixel_y * pixel_y)).ceil
    edge[x,y] = ChunkyPNG::Color.grayscale(val)
  end
end

edge.save('engine_edge.png')
```

**Input/Output**:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just idly, you've copied and pasted the code above wrong (or it was wrong in the blog post and is now fixed?). sobel_x[0][4] is obviously never going to work. It should be [0][1] [1][1] [2][1], etc.

Answer (score 4):

[Sobel Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) Wikipedia page is well descriptive about how to perform it. There other operators such as [Roberts cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberts_Cross) and [Prewitt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prewitt)

Using convolution operation, you can switch the approach by changing the kernel matrix. Below, the implementation of Sobel and Convolution using [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) may help you.

**Sobel:**

```
public class Sobel extends MarvinAbstractImagePlugin{

    // Definitions
    double[][] matrixSobelX = new double[][]{
            {1,     0,  -1},
            {2,     0,  -2},
            {1,     0,  -1}
    };
    double[][] matrixSobelY = new double[][]{
            {-1,    -2,     -1},
            {0,     0,      0},
            {1,     2,      1}
    };

    private MarvinImagePlugin   convolution;

    public void load(){
        convolution = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.convolution.jar");
    }

    public MarvinAttributesPanel getAttributesPanel(){
        return null;
    }
    public void process
    (
        MarvinImage imageIn, 
        MarvinImage imageOut,
        MarvinAttributes attrOut,
        MarvinImageMask mask, 
        boolean previewMode
    )
    {
        convolution.setAttribute("matrix", matrixSobelX);
        convolution.process(imageIn, imageOut, null, mask, previewMode);
        convolution.setAttribute("matrix", matrixSobelY);
        convolution.process(imageIn, imageOut, null, mask, previewMode);
    }
}
```

**Convolution:**

```
public class Convolution extends MarvinAbstractImagePlugin{

    private MarvinAttributesPanel   attributesPanel;
    private MarvinAttributes        attributes;

    public void process
    (
        MarvinImage imageIn, 
        MarvinImage imageOut,
        MarvinAttributes attributesOut,
        MarvinImageMask mask, 
        boolean previewMode
    )
    {
        double[][] matrix = (double[][])attributes.get("matrix");

        if(matrix != null && matrix.length > 0){
            for(int y=0; y<imageIn.getHeight(); y++){
                for(int x=0; x<imageIn.getWidth(); x++){
                    applyMatrix(x, y, matrix, imageIn, imageOut);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyMatrix
    (
        int x,
        int y,
        double[][] matrix,
        MarvinImage imageIn,
        MarvinImage imageOut
    ){

        int nx,ny;
        double resultRed=0;
        double resultGreen=0;
        double resultBlue=0;

        int xC=matrix[0].length/2;
        int yC=matrix.length/2;

        for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<matrix[0].length; j++){
                if(matrix[i][j] != 0){      
                    nx = x + (j-xC);
                    ny = y + (i-yC);

                    if(nx >= 0 && nx < imageOut.getWidth() && ny >= 0 && ny < imageOut.getHeight()){

                        resultRed   +=  (matrix[i][j]*(imageIn.getIntComponent0(nx, ny)));
                        resultGreen +=  (matrix[i][j]*(imageIn.getIntComponent1(nx, ny)));
                        resultBlue  +=  (matrix[i][j]*(imageIn.getIntComponent2(nx, ny)));
                    }


                }



            }
        }

        resultRed   = Math.abs(resultRed);
        resultGreen = Math.abs(resultGreen);
        resultBlue = Math.abs(resultBlue);

        // allow the combination of multiple appications
        resultRed   += imageOut.getIntComponent0(x,y);
        resultGreen += imageOut.getIntComponent1(x,y);
        resultBlue  += imageOut.getIntComponent2(x,y);

        resultRed   = Math.min(resultRed, 255);
        resultGreen = Math.min(resultGreen, 255);
        resultBlue  = Math.min(resultBlue, 255);

        resultRed   = Math.max(resultRed, 0);
        resultGreen = Math.max(resultGreen, 0);
        resultBlue  = Math.max(resultBlue, 0);

        imageOut.setIntColor(x, y, imageIn.getAlphaComponent(x, y), (int)resultRed, (int)resultGreen, (int)resultBlue);
    }

    public void load(){
        attributes = getAttributes();
        attributes.set("matrix", null);
    }

    public MarvinAttributesPanel getAttributesPanel(){
        if(attributesPanel == null){
            attributesPanel = new MarvinAttributesPanel();
            attributesPanel.addMatrixPanel("matrixPanel", "matrix", attributes, 3, 3);
        }
        return attributesPanel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi I am new to this I have created main class and got this error can you tell me how write main class for it ?
Sobel a = new Sobel();
  MarvinImage imgIn = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("unnamed2.jpg");
  MarvinImage imgOut = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("test.jpg");
  a.process(imgIn, imgOut);             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Sobel.process(Sobel.java:41)

Answer (score 4):

Of course, you could use OpenCV for this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(INPUT_IMAGE)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).astype(float)

edge_x = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=3)
edge_y = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=3)    
edge = np.sqrt(edge_x**2 + edge_y**2)    # image can be normalized to 
                                         # fit into 0..255 color space
cv2.imwrite(OUTPUT_IMAGE, edge)
```

Input / Output:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Gx is estimating the gradient in the x-direction (columns) and Gy is estimating the gradient in the y-direction (rows).
So Gy detects horizontal lines, and Gx detects vertical lines.

Comment: This should be comment

Answer (score 0):

All the above mentioned steps in a **R markdown** file. Hopefully this makes it more visual and easier to understand. I needed to implement a sobel filter and this page helped me understand the concepts still I had some trouble in getting it done. So putting it all in one place hopefully it helps.

http://rpubs.com/ghub_24/420754

Answer (score 0):

I use Octave 4.4.1 for image processing and edge detection.
Octave is an open source software which provides functionality of MatLab.
I have used the following code from "https://in.mathworks.com/"
Let us consider that the image is 'k1.jpg'
To implement Sobel edge operator
i=imread('k1.jpg');//To read the image
 pkg load image//Loading image processing Tool Box
 g=rgb2gray(i)//Conversion of image to grayscale
S=edge(g,'Sobel');//Applying Sobel edge detector to g
imshow(S);//To display the image
[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2kGP.png)
[Segmented Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFLjW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in R with the raster package (oriented towards geographic data)

```
library(raster)
sobel <- function(r) {
    fy <- matrix(c(1,0,-1,2,0,-2,1,0,-1)/4, nrow=3)
    fx <- matrix(c(-1,-2,-1,0,0,0,1,2,1)/4 , nrow=3)
    rx <- focal(r, fx)
    ry <- focal(r, fy)
    sqrt(rx^2 + ry^2)
}

b <- brick("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnxa6.jpg")
plotRGB(b)
s <- stack(lapply(1:3, function(i) sobel(b[[i]])))
plotRGB(s)

# or
ss <- mean(s)
plot(ss, col=gray(1:10/10))

# or
bb <- mean(b)
sss <- sobel(bb)
plot(sss, col=gray(1:10/10))
```