# OpenCL Kernel for Canny

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencl, canny-operator, sobel

I'm trying to achieve *`Canny Edge Detection`* with *OpenCL kernel* in very simplified and easy way.

I'm using original `SobelFilter` kernel to do steps like non-maximum suppression and thresholding.

But I'm lost about reaching the pixels and doing the math calculations on them with:

```
__kernel void sobel_filter(__global uchar4* inputImage, __global uchar4* outputImage)
```

Could you give me ideas or show me simple examples to achieve this? It will be highly appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: what error you get when you run it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815687/image-processing-implementing-sobel-filter

Comment: How did you pass data to GPU? As an image buffer or as a simple buffer?

Comment: hypot means `sqrt(x² + y²)` and dividing by 2 means its taking only half for a reason such as using char(so its half of 255 at max) for buffers instead of uchar? Taking sqrt of a float4 also means sqrt of each element (4 of them) separately just as in here for red,green,blue. convert_ is to convert efficiently(probably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobel filter is inhrently separable into X and Y dimensions in kernel execution. So one can scan only on X or only on Y dimensions or both of them in same kernel loop to achieve edge feature detection.

Using user `azer89`'s soution here: [Image Processing - Implementing Sobel Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815687/image-processing-implementing-sobel-filter)

I prepared this kernel:

```
__kernel void postProcess(__global uchar * input, __global uchar * output)
{
    int resultImgSize=1024;
    int pixelX=get_global_id(0)%resultImgSize; // 1-D id list to 2D workitems(each process a single pixel)
    int pixelY=get_global_id(0)/resultImgSize;
    int imgW=resultImgSize;
    int imgH=resultImgSize;


    float kernelx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, 
                           {-2, 0, 2}, 
                           {-1, 0, 1}};
    float kernely[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, 
                           {0,  0,  0}, 
                           {1,  2,  1}};

    // also colors are separable
    int magXr=0,magYr=0; // red
    int magXg=0,magYg=0;
    int magXb=0,magYb=0;

    // Sobel filter
    // this conditional leaves 10-pixel-wide edges out of processing
    if( (pixelX<imgW-10) && (pixelY<imgH-10) && (pixelX>10) && (pixelY>10) )
    { 
        for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
            {            
                int xn = pixelX + a - 1;
                int yn = pixelY + b - 1;

                int index = xn + yn * resultImgSize;
                magXr += input[index*4] * kernelx[a][b];
                magXg += input[index*4+1] * kernelx[a][b];
                magXb += input[index*4+2] * kernelx[a][b];
                magYr += input[index*4] * kernely[a][b];
                magYg += input[index*4+1] * kernely[a][b];
                magYb += input[index*4+2] * kernely[a][b];
            }
         }
    }

    // magnitude of x+y vector
    output[(pixelX+pixelY*resultImgSize)*4]  =sqrt((float)(magXr*magXr + magYr*magYr)) ;
    output[(pixelX+pixelY*resultImgSize)*4+1]=sqrt((float)(magXg*magXg + magYg*magYg)) ;
    output[(pixelX+pixelY*resultImgSize)*4+2]=sqrt((float)(magXb*magXb + magYb*magYb)) ;
    output[(pixelX+pixelY*resultImgSize)*4+3]=255;

}
```

Indices were multipled with 4 here because they were interpreted as `uchar`  array as kernel parameters. `uchar` is a single byte in OpenCL(at least for my system).

Here is a video of this:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

**Sobel Filter Example**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtkK405xuO4)

if it works for you too, you should accept `azer89`'s solution. But this is not very optimized and may take 1-2 milliseconds for a low end GPU and even more with only a CPU for 1024x1024 image. The image data is sent to an OpenCL buffer(not image buffer) using a byte array(of C# language) and kernel launch options are:

- Global range = 1024*1024 (1 thread per pixel processing)
- Local range = 256 (this is not important)
- Buffer copy size 1024*1024*4 (bytes for rgba format)

also kernelx and kernely 2D arrays here were `float` so making them `char` could make it faster. Also you may check results(clamp, divide, ...) if result looks a lot more colorful than its expected. Host side representation/interpretation is also important to handle underflow and overlow of colors.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Huseyin for your answer and guidance. It *worked like a* **charm!**

Comment: Put more effort on C++ side. Then you wouldn't have any difficulties if you ever move to sycl and similar syntactic up to date opencl sugar.

Answer (score 1):

ARM compute library has canny implementation
[Canny CL kernel](https://github.com/ARM-software/ComputeLibrary/blob/master/src/core/CL/cl_kernels/canny.cl)

Comment: *Thank you for guidance!*